# Application crashes during execution

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to make a navigation drawer but every time it's executed the application crashes. I am a beginner. Please, let me know if you need any more info and thanks

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.pixalstudio.navigationdrawer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] mTitles;
        DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        ListView mDrawerList;

        mTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawerItems);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer_listview);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter((ListAdapter) new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mTitles));

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void selectItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationSelection.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        default:

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationSelection.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        default:

        }
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.pixalstudio.navigationdrawer.MainActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#757575" >
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_listview"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#FF9800"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice" >
    </ListView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

LogCat

```
    07-07 16:53:20.301: D/OpenGLRenderer(1775): Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
07-07 16:53:20.305: D/(1775): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb42d7750, tid 1775
07-07 16:53:20.322: D/Atlas(1775): Validating map...
07-07 16:53:20.398: D/libEGL(1775): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
07-07 16:53:20.399: D/libEGL(1775): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
07-07 16:53:20.414: D/libEGL(1775): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
07-07 16:53:20.427: D/(1775): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xaf039480, tid 1793
07-07 16:53:20.638: I/OpenGLRenderer(1775): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-07 16:53:20.728: D/OpenGLRenderer(1775): Enabling debug mode 0
07-07 16:53:20.900: W/EGL_emulation(1775): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-07 16:53:20.900: W/OpenGLRenderer(1775): Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xaf035860, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-07 16:53:20.940: D/AndroidRuntime(1775): Shutting down VM
07-07 16:53:20.940: D/AndroidRuntime(1775): --------- beginning of crash
07-07 16:53:20.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1775): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 16:53:20.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1775): Process: com.pixalstudio.navigationdrawer, PID: 1775
07-07 16:53:20.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1775): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.pixalstudio.navigationdrawer/com.pixalstudio.navigationdrawer.LocationSelection}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.pixalstudio.navigationdrawer.LocationSelection cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
07-07 16:53:20.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
07-07 16:53:20.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
07-07 16:53:20.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
07-07 16:53:20.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
07-07 16:53:20.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-07 16:53:20.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-07 16:53:20.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
07-07 16:53:20.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-07 16:53:20.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-07 16:53:20.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
07-07 16:53:20.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
07-07 16:53:20.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1775): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.pixalstudio.navigationdrawer.LocationSelection cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
07-07 16:53:20.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1066)
07-07 16:53:20.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
07-07 16:53:20.941: E/AndroidRuntime(1775):     ... 10 more
07-07 16:53:23.310: I/Process(1775): Sending signal. PID: 1775 SIG: 9
```

Menifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pixalstudio.navigationdrawer"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".LocationSelection"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCATIONSELECTION" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: what is the exception you are getting?

Comment: We'll need a stack trace.  You can get one by running the application in debug mode under whichever android IDE you're using, and looking into the logcat output.

Comment: logcat added mate. please help.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if the problem is in your MainActivity.  Can you post your manifest?

Comment: It seems that `LocationSelection` is not an `Activity` and you are trying to start it as one.

Comment: yes. If I switch it from Fragment to an Activity. will it work? sorry I am newbie.

Comment: I think it will.  @Titus has the right idea.

Comment: Can you provide the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Okay. @Titus - now it do not crash but it directly launches the other activity than Main, Let me give u menifest file.

Comment: @JasonPortnoy Menifest added. Please help. It directly launches the second activity and not the activity_main. :(

Comment: That is probably because `savedInstanceState` is `null` which means that `selectItem(0)` is called which starts the other activity.

Comment: @Titus what should I change please suggest.

Comment: @Titus thank you so much. I deleted if (savedInstanceState == null) {
   selectItem(0);  and this workd, sorry to bother you but one more question. what if I want to launch LocationSelection activity when first item is DrawerList is clicked??

Comment: It would seem the LocationSelection.java does not inherit from activity, provide that aswell.